# ObjectId mongodb equivalent for mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

So, for the record, this is working but we are purely using mongoose, yet I had to import {ObjectId} from mongodb for it to find the ID of the Candidate.

To summarize: We are creating Candidates (Candidates Collection) and for each Candidate we have/insert some Interviews. Each Interview has its own _id (each Interview is inserted to an Interviews Collection aswell) and has the Candidate _id corresponding for each entry.
When we want to delete that Candidate, we need to delete ALL the Interviews that have it's _id.

I still don't understand mongoose 100%, so maybe I missed something, but I couldn't seem to make it work without using mongodb {ObjectId}

```
import Candidate from "../../../../models/candidateModel";
import Interview from "../../../../models/interviewModel";
import db from "../../../../utils/db";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { isAuth } from "../../../../utils/auth";
import { ObjectId } from "mongodb";

const handler = nc();
handler.use(isAuth);

handler.delete(async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    await db.connect();
    const candidate = await Candidate.findById(req.query.id);

    const candidateId = candidate._id.toString();

    if (candidate) {
        await candidate.remove();
        await Interview.deleteMany({
            candidate: new ObjectId(candidateId),
        });
        await db.disconnect();
        res.send({ message: "Perfil de Candidato apagado" });
    } else {
        await db.disconnect();
        res
            .status(404)
            .send({ message: "Não foi possivel encontrar o Perfil de Candidato" });
    }
});
```

Please gimme answers considering this APP is using react/next/typescript/mongoose/axios.

```
        await Interview.deleteMany({
            candidate: new ObjectId(candidateId),
        });
```

This is the part I want to know. If someone needs to look at the Schemas, just ask me here, and I will post them both.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mongoose also has an ObjectId at Schema.Types.ObjectId https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#:~:text=Mixed-,ObjectId,-Array

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose also has an ObjectId at Schema.Types.ObjectId here: [Mongooses ObjectId Type](http://Mongoose%20also%20has%20an%20ObjectId%20at%20Schema.Types.ObjectId%20https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#:%7E:text=Mixed-,ObjectId,-Array)

Mongoose also reads strings to match for objectids so you don't have to use new ObjectId("stringid")

And mongoose has a getter for id where you get the _id as a string instead of using the _id field and getting an ObjectId.
This "id" is called a virtual field jsut fyi.
Which you can read more about here: [document id getter](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-id)